# How to use FIND_IN_SET and sum column in my SQL query

Tags: sql, mariadb

Can anyone help me? I have a table result like this:

| id_user | score | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 30 | play |
| 001 | 40 | play |
| 001 | 30 | redeem |
| 002 | 20 | play |
| 002 | 30 | redeem |

I want to sum column score group by id_user base on type 'play' and after that I want show ranking using find_in_set. Like this is the result of the table that I want to display:

| id_user | total | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 70 | 1 |
| 002 | 20 | 2 |

Previously I used the rank() function in MySQL version 10.4, but it does not work in MySQL version 15.1. This is my previous query:

```
SELECT id_user,  SUM(score) AS total,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total DESC) AS rank
FROM result
WHERE type='play'
GROUP BY id_user
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Do you get a specifc error mesasage? Or an unexpected result? Please be clear about exactly what goes wrong. Also, are you really using MariaDB because those look like MariaDB version numbers, not mySQL?

Comment: MySQL currently is up to version 8+ and MariaDB only up to 10.6+. So, what is mysql ver 15.1? You better run `SELECT @@version` to get the correct version.

Comment: I'm so sory, apparently the error is in mariadb version 5.5, and I read it [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rank/) function rank is available in mariadb version 10.2, but how to make ranking in mariadb version 5.5 ?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY total DESC) AS rank FROM result where type='play' GROUP BY id' at line 1` this is the error message, thank you

Comment: You need to upgrade before you can use that feature

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your query. It's working now. Instead of column alias `total` SUM(score) needs to be used in order by clause of Rank() function's over(). And since `Rank` is a reserve word I used `rnk` instead.

DB-Fiddle:

```
 create table result (id_user varchar(5), score int, type varchar(20));
 insert into result values('001',30 ,'play');
 insert into result values('001',40 ,'play');
 insert into result values('001',30 ,'redeem');
 insert into result values('002',20 ,'play');
 insert into result values('002',30 ',redeem');
```

Query:

```
 select id_user,  SUM(score) AS total, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC) AS rnk FROM result where type='play' GROUP BY id_user
```

Output:

| id_user | total | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 70 | 1 |
| 002 | 20 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=953636effb5d0f7115b32758fcffaf47)*

If your MySQL version doesn't support rank() you can use subquery to achieve same result:

Query:
select id_user,  SUM(score) AS total,
coalesce((select count(distinct id_user) from result r2
where type='play'
group by id_user
having sum(r2.score)>sum(r.score) ),0)+1 AS rnk
FROM result r where type='play'
GROUP BY id_user

Output:

| id_user | total | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 70 | 1 |
| 002 | 20 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=66681dc6bc259c7c3a3a52a06ba9cd78)*

Comment: I'm so sory, apparently the error is in mariadb version 5.5, and I read it [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rank/) function rank is available in mariadb version 10.2, but how to make ranking in mariadb version 5.5 ?